# how to unselect a devexpress data grid row when we click with ctrl+ mouse left button wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, devexpress

I have a devexpress data grid with data. I am able to select multiple rows and on button click I am unselecting all the rows perfectly. but the problem is I am unable to deselect the row with ctrl+mouse left click.

actually the row is getting deselected, when I check the visiblerowcount value, but in the UI it is still showing as selected row.

How can I do unselection?
this is the code for selecting all the rows of my grid

```
MyGrid.TableView.SelectAll();
SelectedRecords.Text = "" + MyGridVisibleRowCount;
```

and for unselection all the rows on button click I am doing in this way

```
MyGrid.ClearSelection();
MyGrid.View.FocusedRowHandle = -1;
SelectedRecords.Text = "" + 0;
```

any help highly appericated.

Thanks
Ganesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is quite old. But for newly comers;

1- set a field as "bool isCtrlPressed=false;" outside of any methods.

2- Handle gridcontrol or gridview's keydown events and set "isCtrlPressed = e.Control" in that event's method.

3- Handle gridcontrol or gridview mouseup. set

```
var hitInfo = gridView.CalcHitInfo(e.Location); 
if(isCtrlPressed && hitInfo.InRow || hitInfo.InRowCell){
    if(isCtrlPressed && gridView.IsRowSelected(hitInfo.RowHandle){
        gridView.UnselectRow(hitInfo.RowHandle);
    }
}
```

4- finally don't forget to release isCtrlPressed by handling gridcontrol or gridview's mouseup and reset "isCtrlPressed = false"

If you stuck at hitInfo class, you can navigate inside DevExpress's Support Center. I didn't test this code but may be necessary a rowHandle check such as it is equal or not GridControl.AutoFilterRowHandle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `UnselectRow` method. Try this piece of code :

```
MyGrid.BeginUpdate();

for (int i = 0; i < MyGrid.RowCount; i++)
{
    if (MyGrid.IsRowSelected(i))
        MyGrid.UnselectRow(i);
}

MyGrid.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: I am able to unselect all the rows, but the problem was when I use ctrl+mouse left button click, I want the row to be unselected. When I check in the visiblerowcount, the row count is decreased, but in the UI the row is not getting un-selected @Fares